# If I save created view and visit the view page it showing only filter field

Tags: views

I am new to drupal and I am trying to create `view` for my `content type`, I followed the steps using a tutorial but I am not able to see the preview of the created content view if I save and visit the view page it showing only filter field. Please help me.[image]

I have used the following method to create the view.

1) click on `view` and Add new name.

2) enter the name and in the show field selected the content then i specified my created content in type of field, and newest first in the sorted by field.

3) selected the table format.

4) added the fields of specified content with the help of search box where in i have given the content name so all related fields show up.

5) added the filter field from specified content.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there is content of this particular content type?

Comment: @Aparna: yes I am very sure,I have created the content type with all those specified fields.

Comment: try only adding the content title if it works then there must be some dependency with one of the fields you have added.

Comment: if I select content title, it showing some other content type title. I am not getting specified content title. Please assist me on this from long time  I am trying on this.

Comment: have you added any relationship in the view? one more thing try adding age as field in field list.

Comment: no age is some other content field , now when i selected the field from specified content filter field is also not showing of, i have added the one more screen shot please take a look

Comment: i think you have  added some **Contextual filters** as relationship, thats y **Preview with contextual filters:** textbox will show in preview area. Please check it again.

Comment: @Abin: i have not added any contextual filters.

Comment: Can you pls chk inside that **Advanced** tab..

Comment: @Abin: i have posted the screen shot of it, i have not added any contextual filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you set  "age expose field  required" it cause in first load nothing show up till user enter something in filter.
try it with removing "Required" checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Hai Zhilevan, i have not mentioned it as required, dont know where iam doing mistake its becoming nightmare to me.

Comment: @kashish dont worry I am here to help you ;) ,  tell me if you enter something in age the apply  results showed up?

Comment: @kashish dont forget close question (with accept)

Comment: @ Zhilevan: sure ):

Comment: @kashish tnx ;)